# how to round off the tabs above and below the current tab in the nav bar, also shadow the nav bar except the current tab

Tags: css, jinja2, nav, border-radius

I've never asked a css question before so apologies in advance.

This is what my nav bar looks like currently
[image]
[full sized image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj6qQ.png)

Two things I really want to achieve:

1. round of the tabs just above and below the current tab
   (in this picture it would be *Suggestions* and *About Us*)
2. shadow the nav bar on the right side except the current tab

(I'm using jinja2 btw. Cannot hard code the corners since the current tab is not fixed)

I have no idea about 1. but I tried 2. and this is the unsatisfied result:
[image]

would like to get rid of the abrupt corners
[image]

This is my current stylesheet

```html
:root {
    /* colour palette */
    --cream : hsl(40, 100%, 96%);
    --cream-light:hsl(40, 100%, 98%);
    --coffee: hsl(40,  14%, 62%);
    --purple: hsl(258, 14%, 62%);
    --dark  : hsl(109,  7%, 33%);
    --green : hsl(128, 30%, 42%);
    --green2: hsl(140, 15%, 55%);
    --green2-dark: hsl(140, 11%, 36%);

    /*  */
    --shadow-in: inset 1px .15rem .3rem -.1rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), inset 1px .1rem .2rem -.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset -1px -1px .3rem -.1rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), inset -1px -1px .2rem -.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    --shadow-nav: .3rem 0 .6rem -.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), .2rem 0 .4rem -.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    --shadow-current: inset .3rem .3rem .6rem -.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), inset .2rem .2rem .4rem -.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    --shadow-hover: inset 1px .3rem .6rem -.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), inset 1px .2rem .4rem -.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset -1px -1px .6rem -.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25), inset -1px -1px .4rem -.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    /* themes */
    --nav-bg   : var(--green2-dark);
    --nav-text : white;
    --nav-hover: hsl(140, 11%, 27%);
    --main     : var(--cream );
    --text     : var(--dark  );
    --highlight: var(--green);
    --card     : var(--cream-light);
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background: var(--nav-bg);
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
a {
    color: var(--text);
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: var(--green);
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 18%;
    height: 100vh;
    /*box-shadow: var(--shadow-nav);*/
    /*box-shadow: .3rem 0 .6rem rgba(50, 93, 50, 0.25), .2rem 0 .4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);*/
    background: var(--nav-bg);
}
nav h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10%;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    height: 1.8rem;

    background: var(--nav-bg);
    color: var(--nav-text);
    transition: margin .5s, padding .5s, border .5s, background .5s, color .3s;
}
/*nav div.current {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: .9rem;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(140, 11%, 36%) 50%, hsl(40, 100%, 96%) 50%);
}
nav div.current:hover {
    padding-right: 0;
}*/
nav h2.current {
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    border-radius: .5rem 0 0 .5rem;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow-current);
    background: var(--main);
    color: var(--text);
}
nav h2:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10%;
    padding-left: 15%;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow-hover);
    background: var(--nav-hover);
    color: var(--nav-text);
}
main {
    padding-left: 22.5%;
    padding-right: 7.5%;
    min-height: 100vh;

    background: var(--main);
    color: var(--text);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main h1 {
    color: var(--green2);
}
footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: .35rem;
    padding: .25rem;
    padding-right: 2.5rem;
    border-radius: .25rem;

    font: .5rem sans-serif;
    text-align: right;

    background: hsl(40, 39%, 90%);
    box-shadow: var(--shadow-in);
}
```

and this is layout.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Library</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        {% include 'navigation.html' %}
    </nav>
    <main>
        {% block main %} {% endblock %}
        <footer>Copyright 2021 mightbesimon | github.com/mightbesimon</footer>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is `navigation.html`

```html
{% for url, name in (('/'           , 'Home'         ),
                     ('/register'   , 'Register'     ),
                     ('/login'      , 'Login'        ),
                     ('/suggestions', 'Suggestions'  ),
                     ('/catalogue'  , 'Our Catalogue'),
                     ('/aboutus'    , 'About Us'     ),
                     ('/contact'    , 'Contact'      ),
) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">
        <!-- <div {% if url_for(request.endpoint, **request.view_args)==url %} class="current" {% endif %}> -->
            <h2 {% if url_for(request.endpoint, **request.view_args)==url %} class="current" {% endif %}>
                {{ name }}
            </h2>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a try to

- `drop-shadow()` (but it will do on any translucide edges => **text too unfortunately**) to draw the shadow via `filter`  .
- `box-shadow` from `.current` to paint the nav `background`
- `overflow:hidden` on `nav` to avoid shadow to bleed on `main`
- `position: relative` for `h2` to remain on top of the shadow  & `static` for `.current`

here is the idea of possible update

```
:root {
  /* colour palette */
  --cream: hsl(40, 100%, 96%);
  --cream-light: hsl(40, 100%, 98%);
  --coffee: hsl(40, 14%, 62%);
  --purple: hsl(258, 14%, 62%);
  --dark: hsl(109, 7%, 33%);
  --green: hsl(128, 30%, 42%);
  --green2: hsl(140, 15%, 55%);
  --green2-dark: hsl(140, 11%, 36%);

  /*  */
  --shadow-in: inset 1px 0.15rem 0.3rem -0.1rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    inset 1px 0.1rem 0.2rem -0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset -1px -1px 0.3rem -0.1rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    inset -1px -1px 0.2rem -0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  --shadow-nav: 0.3rem 0 0.6rem -0.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    0.2rem 0 0.4rem -0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  --shadow-current: inset 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.6rem -0.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    inset 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.4rem -0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  --shadow-hover: inset 1px 0.3rem 0.6rem -0.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    inset 1px 0.2rem 0.4rem -0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset -1px -1px 0.6rem -0.2rem rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25),
    inset -1px -1px 0.4rem -0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  /* themes */
  --nav-bg: var(--green2-dark);
  --nav-text: white;
  --nav-hover: hsl(140, 11%, 27%);
  --main: var(--cream);
  --text: var(--dark);
  --highlight: var(--green);
  --card: var(--cream-light);
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  background: var(--nav-bg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
a {
  color: var(--text);
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: var(--green);
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: -1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 18%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  min-height:100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.3rem 0.3rem 0.6rem);
  
}
nav h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10%;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  height: 1.8rem;
  transition: margin 0.5s, padding 0.5s, border 0.5s, background 0.5s,
    color 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--nav-text);
}

nav h2.current:hover {
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-hover), 0 0 0 100vw var(--nav-bg);
}
nav h2.current {
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax var(--nav-bg);
  color: var(--text);
  position: static;
}
nav h2:hover {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-hover);
  background: var(--nav-hover);
  color: var(--nav-text);
}
main {
  padding-left: 22.5%;
  padding-right: 7.5%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--main);
  color: var(--text);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main h1 {
  color: var(--green2);
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.35rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font: 0.5rem sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  background: hsl(40, 39%, 90%);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-in);
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()
>
> **Note:** This function is somewhat similar to the `box-shadow` property. The `box-shadow` property creates a rectangular shadow behind an element's entire box, while the `drop-shadow()` filter function creates a shadow that conforms to the shape (alpha channel) of the image itself.

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyrillus :) Since no one else has provided an answer in a few weeks, I'm accepting your answer as the best and only solution so far. Cheers